# custom wsdl based on a condiction?

Tags: .net, web-services, soap

Well I want to generate a different WSDL based on a condition I mean hide some method keep all complex type just show or hide some method.

my question

there's any way to get some parameters on the URL to get the wsdl and then evaluate the param a render a custom WSDL?

Example host.dev/myservice.wsdl?param=role1 and with reflection delete some property and those method hide on execution time.

The problem
I got many client to my service and they use to fetch the wsdl to make the client not for consumption, they just get the wsdl pointing to the origin and not all of then need all methods it's just to give them a clean solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really want to do so? Basically WSDL is an interface definition, a contract that should be as static & immutable as possible. Maybe applying some sort of security (an access ticket extra argument?) is a better way to make methods accessible or not.

Comment: It would really help if you could explain your original problem X, so we can help assess whether your [solution Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) actually is the best way to solve X. For example if you think your service exposes too many methods, it probably does and you can better split it up into multiple services, one per business area.

Comment: _"not all of then need all methods"_ - so, like being said, create separate services.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think there is a way to do that. It doesn't usually hurt to have things in the WSDL you don't use, why do you need this at all? If you do, it'd probably make sense to split it into other services so you have separate WSDLs. If your client needs all of the WSDLs, they can reference them all.

Comment: actually I think same like you but if could be possible to do it it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Actually .net's WSDL generator works by processing a type's methods. I once had written a object to web service wrapper which publishes any object as a full blown web service (Dynamic Web Services was the name of the feature). Since code belongs to my previous employer, I cannot show a code example here but I can give you some directions from my memory.

1. WSDL generator is actually a class which you can call by passing a type.
2. Since `Type` class itself is not sealed, you can inherit from it. Your custom `Type` class provides names and parameters for the WSDL generator.

After that point it is up to your imagination which methods you will provide. I actually implemented more than that, I wrote another piece of code that converts dictionary like objects to web service data contracts by creating type on the fly by exposing dictionary keys as property names. As I've said before it is all up to your imagination.